How to Improve Apache OpenNLP Output Using Custom Trained Models in Spring Boot?
I'm currently using Apache OpenNLP with a Spring Boot REST API, and I'm facing some issues with the output of the model. Here's what I'm experiencing:

Input text: "I'm Arun Vinc. What is your name?"

Output: 'm ? arun i is name vinc what your


The output isn't coherent, and I suspect that the pre-trained models I'm using might not be well-suited for my application. After researching online, I found that I might need to train my own .bin models using appropriate corpora datasets to get better results.
Spring Boot REST API: This is the code I’m using to load the models and perform the NLP tasks:
@Service
public class OpenNLPService {

    private SentenceDetectorME sentenceDetector;
    private TokenizerME tokenizer;
    private POSTaggerME posTagger;

    public OpenNLPService() throws Exception {
        try (InputStream sentenceModelIn = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("models/en-sent.bin");
             InputStream tokenModelIn = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("models/en-token.bin");
             InputStream posModelIn = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("models/en-pos-maxent.bin")) {

            SentenceModel sentenceModel = new SentenceModel(sentenceModelIn);
            TokenizerModel tokenModel = new TokenizerModel(tokenModelIn);
            POSModel posModel = new POSModel(posModelIn);

            this.sentenceDetector = new SentenceDetectorME(sentenceModel);
            this.tokenizer = new TokenizerME(tokenModel);
            this.posTagger = new POSTaggerME(posModel);
        }
    }

    public String processText(String text) {
        String[] sentences = sentenceDetector.sentDetect(text);
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        for (String sentence : sentences) {
            String[] tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(sentence);
            String[] posTags = posTagger.tag(tokens);
            result.append(String.join(" ", tokens)).append("\n");
        }

        return result.toString();
    }
}

What I’ve Tried

Pre-Trained Models: I’m currently using the default pre-trained models (en-sent.bin, en-token.bin, en-pos-maxent.bin) from Apache OpenNLP.

Research: I’ve read that the accuracy and relevance of these models can be improved by training them with a more suitable corpus. However, I’m not sure which corpora would be best for general English text processing, nor how to properly train these models.


Error Messages and Debugging

No specific errors, but the output is not meaningful, which suggests that the model may not be well-suited for the input data.

